# Form Data doesn't save the image correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to save Form Data with its information but when I do so I get a weird looking object that I think the server is refusing to accept and returns a 500 error.

Here is how I'm handling it:

```
const formData = new FormData();
let currentlyUploaded = e.target.files[0];
formData.append(currentlyUploaded.name, currentlyUploaded);
// passing the data in function then ...
```

And this is how it looks when I console it later before the call, and it doesn't look correct. [image: console log]

here is the route:

```
router.post(
  `${prefix}/create-quiz`,
  userAuth,
  upload.single("file"),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.userId });

      const newQuiz = new Quiz({
        purchaseCoins: req.body.purchaseCoins,
        privacy: req.body.privacy,
        created_by: req.params.userId,
        category: req.body.category,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        difficulty: req.body.difficulty,
        questions: req.body.questions,
        thumbnail: req.file.filename,
      });

      await newQuiz.save();
      user.quizzes.push(newQuiz._id);
      await user.save();

      return res.status(201).json({
        message: "Finally , quiz created properly!",
        success: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // return res.status(500).json({
      //   message: "Can't save this quiz try again, check if it already exists",
      //   success: false,
      // });
      console.log("errorium: ", error)
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Why did you expand the prototype? Is there something of interest to you?

Comment: Did you write something else? I get an error that e.target is undefined.!

Comment: @user15517071 to show to you dude

Comment: @YarinLevi what do you mean?

Comment: You didn't actually show the contents of the filename field. It is the field's [object prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes). Can you explain why you are putting FormData into a field named "filename"? I am confused by that.

Comment: @user15517071 I'm will take it on database, check the new update